# return multiple rows in a single row resultset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three MSSQL tables. First table is item transactions,  The second is Items table (where I get the name of Item and the other specs of the particular item)
and the third table is item delivery type table(like Box, Pack and Pieces and their converting factors)

first table fields;

```
..., itemid, trtype, trdate, amount, price, dlvid ...
```

second table fields;

```
..., itemid, itemcode, itemname ...
```

third table fields;

```
... dlvid, IsMain, dlvname, convfactor ...
```

And

```
11 1 Box  [1]

12 0 Pack [25]   (1 box = 25 Packs)

13 0 Pcs  [375]  (1 Pack = 15 Pcs, 1 Box = 375 Pcs)
```

Figures in brackets are the converting factors

Before, I was putting them in a gridview. itemname(from 2.nd table), trtype, trdate, amount (from 1.st table) and the dlvname (from 3.rd table) then it was ok.

But now I have to display all of the delivery type in one row with the calculation like;

Faber Drawing Pencil 3B  | Out | 05.06.2018  | 6 Box, 150 Packs, 2,250
 Pcs ...

Could you please help me with these.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Selecting data `from ItemTransactions as IT inner join Items as I on IT.ItemId = I.ItemId inner join DeliveryType as DT on DT.DlvId = IT.DlvId` will get all of the related data into a single row for each item in each transaction. Then it is a simple matter of multiplying the values in the appropriate columns to get the extended values.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Dear @HABO thanks for your advice. I already got the data in one particular DeliveryType but I should read the other two within the same query also to calculate the extended values.

Answer (score -1):

First of all I would like to let you know that your question is very low quality. It is very hard to understand your tables and data types.  It is even not clear to understand in which case you are having problem?

So for the next time pleae read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Here is your answer:

```
select 
  ...
  STRING_AGG (concat(amount, ' ', trtype), ',') within group (order by amount asc)
from 
  Table 1 
Inner Join Table2 on ....
inner join table3 on ...
```

Comment: You did not mention relationships and column names which is needed to be used in query. With that much Informatlon this is what I can do for you.

Comment: I did mentioned column names.take a closer look and read again.
Thanks anyway.